# LaunchImage для приложения iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone, apple

Чтобы поставить Launch Image для приложения, XCode просит загрузить для каждого разрешения свою картинку. Вопрос в следующем - могу ли я загрузить только один Launch Image для самого высокого разрешения, а остальные оставить пустыми или вообще отключить? Будет ли показываться Launch Image при запуске на других (более низких) разрешениях?

P.S
Действительно не понимаю зачем для *каждого* дисплея нужна своя картинка, в чём проблема ресайзить её автоматически? Apple, что с вами не так? Приложение очень быстро распухает в размерах от всех этих картинок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch Image Source отображает изображение только для своего разрешения.
Т.е. если Вы сделаете Launch Image Source только для Retina HD 5.5, то у Вас стартовый экран будет только для iPhone 6+, на остальных будет запуск с черного экрана.

Если у Вас приложение только для iOS 8, то можете использовать Launch Screen File, т.е. добавить в проект Launch Screen.xib и с помощью Auto Layout и Size Classes сделать один стартовый экран для всех устройств.

Comment: Хотелось бы iOS 7 тоже поддерживать, если верить статистике на ней всё еще 20% пользователей. В общем я так понял, что если нужна поддержка iOS 7, то выбора нет - нужно загружать для каждого разрешения свою картинку. С иконками приложения видимо такая-же ситуация.

Comment: @АлександрСтепанов Вы правильно поняли. На счёт иконок точно не могу сказать, но чаще всего иконки много места не занимают. И возможно, что на иконки ругаться тоже будет и не только Xcode, но и Apple при проверке приложения. Вы можете и не использовать Launch Image Source, а создать, к примеру кастомный стартовый экран в своем стартовом классе, но при это будет такая ситуация: Когда Вы запустите приложение, то у Вас на секунду будет черный экран, потом появиться Ваш кастомный стартовый экран, а потом и приложение

Comment: Спасибо, может быть попробую и такой вариант.

Comment: @АлександрСтепанов для иконок Вы можете использовать такой удобный плагин https://github.com/kaphacius/IconMaker
Указываете один большой размер, и дальше плагин сделает всю работу за Вас

Comment: Для экономии места максимально сжимать изображения с контролем качества картинки.